# Does stacking o-rings provide the same result as using a thicker o-ring?

Tags: keyboard

I plan to add o-rings in my mechanical keyboard. Does stacking o-rings provide the same result as using a thicker o-ring in terms of key travel, from the standpoint of the keyboard user?

The goal of adding o-ring is obtaining reducing key travel to be as low as possible (without having to hammer the keys for them to actuate).

---

For example, I could use two o-rings stacked on top of each other (1.5mm + 2.5mm) like this:

[image]

or directly use a 4mm o-ring.

Let's assume the o-rings have the same inner diameter, and are applied to a Cherry MX key switch. I am thinking of using 40A o-ring.

Comment: What does the thicker o-ring hope to achieve?

Comment: @Moab Reducing the travel distance.

Comment: @CloseVoter Can you expand on why it is off-topic here? As far as I know it is on-topic.

Comment: In what way would you expect there could be a difference?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am not sure the physics of two stacked o-rings are the same as the physics of a thicker o-ring, but my knowledge in that field is too far behind me, and I don't know whether it would impact the keyboard user. No difference is a valid answer.

Comment: @CloseVoter3 Can you expand on what is unclear?

Comment: I voted to close as unclear (and commented).  You sort of clarified (distance vs. compressibility?), but to be honest, I don't see keyboard redesign or the physics of o-rings as on-topic. Impact on the user is borderline on-topic.  If the o-ring combination actually does make a difference (which seems unlikely), the result would probably vary by keyboard (over-broad).  You show 2 (3?) diameter rings, so nesting is another variable.  You could easily test this for a case-specific answer, but as a theoretical question, it's likely to attract opinion-based answers.  Do you agree?

Comment: @fixer1234: Thanks for the comment. I don't think the result would vary by keyboard, but I have restricted the question in case. I have also added the mentioned regarding the inner diameter of the o-ring in order to mitigate the nesting issue you referred to. There might be some opinion-based answers, but I am mostly looking for objective ones (e.g. blind folded test). Lastly, meta  [What is our stance on questions pertaining to keyboard modding?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11478/116475)

Comment: The only way to answer this would be to test it.  Why not do that?

Comment: @fixer1234 Not free and would take a few days (shipping). But I guess I'll resort to it if nobody shares their experience.

Comment: As most have mentioned, it would very unlikely have any impact and I agree with them.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: Thanks, you are welcome to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: If distance is the only reason, I see no difference between stacked and thicker as long at the installed heights of the two different methods are the same.

Comment: @Moab: One comment mentions limiting travel distance; another mentions the physics of the rings, which implies more than travel distance (one of the things making the question unclear).  If it was simply distance, there is no need for a question (1.5+2.5=4.0).  The implication is that the question is broader (e.g., key resistance or other characteristics).  I tried to address that in an answer.  It isn't clear that your edit reflects the full intent of the question, and it makes my answer irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe I am getting something totally wrong: but how would the addition of o-rings impact the key travel at all? The only thing I see it doing is you needing more pressure to push down the key, because you don't only have to overcome the force of the spring, but also of the elastic o-ring. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TJJ o-rings would reduce the post activation key travel. I.e., the distance between the operating point (typically between 1.2mm and 2mm on a cherry) and the total key travel ( typically between 3.4 and 4 mm ). I have put some graphs on http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2581/40

Answer (score 3):

If the question is strictly about limiting key travel, it could be answered by simple arithmetic:

```
1.5mm + 2.5mm = 4.0mm
```

Any combination of o-rings with the desired total thickness would yield essentially the same result and the question would be a trivial one.

However, the comments clarify the nature of the anticipated difference: the physics of the rings and impact on the user.  So, I will assume that the question is about more than simply limiting travel, and is concerned with additional characteristics that would affect the user, like how key resistance would compare.

Start with the case of two 2mm thick rings.  These would have different mechanics than one 4mm ring.  Rings of unequal thicknesses would have still different mechanics, but none of that would necessarily make a difference in key characteristics.

Think of the cross section.  Two 2mm thick rings would have 1/2 the material of one 4mm ring, and theoretically, you could stack them so that the thickest portions were concentric.  The reduced material would provide less resistance to compression than a single 4mm ring.

If the rings are of unequal thickness and the same inner or outer diameter, one will nest inside the other.  Now, in addition to compression, you will have other dynamics, like stretching of the outer ring.  However, the total material will be closer to that of a single 4mm ring.  So the mechanics get very complicated, and you can get situations like less resistance to compression up to a point, then more resistance (compared to two equal rings).

The elasticity of the material will effect the dynamics, and many materials have different characteristics under stretching and compression.  So all of those factors affect how it will behave outside the keyboard.

Now stick this system inside a keyboard.  The key stem and the cavity under the key limit how much the ring material can move/spread.  This is basically beyond the ability to calculate a result except perhaps by simulation.

But you still aren't at an answer.  What role is this playing in the key mechanics?  You still have to be able to actuate the key, so there is a narrow range of sizes and materials that will allow sufficient motion for the key to work.  Once you have that, it affects how far the key will travel as a function of how much pressure you exert, and there are limits to travel.

So while the mechanics of ring combinations are different, you could still end up in a working range where the difference has no effect on what happens with the key.

The only practical way to determine an answer is to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

As most have mentioned, it would very unlikely have any impact and I agree with them.

Answer (score 1):

It decreases travel distance significantly and the key can end up being 'mushy'. While some people like that feeling most don't so O-rings aren't really that popular.

GMK produces [QMX Clips](https://uniqey.net/en/accessories/) which result in similar silencing performance, at a greatly decreased effect on travel distance.

There are also landing pads, which are basically small foam cut outs that sit around the key on the plate, although they are quite cheap, your mileage may vary as they aren't the best solution. I'd go with QMK clips if I were you